# エクセル計算式=Σ(ai×bi)のA=Σaiを計算するvbaを探しています。

Tags: vba

(例)
=1*2+3*4       　　　　　　　　　      A=4
=1*2+3　　    　　　　　　　　         A=4
=R1C1*R1C2+R1C3*R7C8  　　A=R1C1+R1C3
他の言語でも参考のページがあれば教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

ーーーーーーー
20180407追加
ありがとうございます。

```
Sub aTest()
    Cells(1, 5) = "=1*2+3*(-4)"
    Cells(2, 5) = "=1*2+3"
    Cells(3, 5) = "=3+1*2"
    Cells(4, 1) = "1"
    Cells(4, 2) = "2"
    Cells(4, 3) = "3"
    Cells(4, 4) = "4"
    Cells(4, 5) = "=R4C1*R4C2+R4C3*R4C4"
'
    Cells(1, 7) = sigmaA(Cells(1, 5)) '4
    Cells(2, 7) = sigmaA(Cells(2, 5)) '4
    Cells(3, 7) = sigmaA(Cells(3, 5)) '4
    Cells(4, 7) = sigmaA(Cells(4, 5)) '4
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

こんな感じ？

```
Option Explicit
Function sigmaA(arg As Range) As String
Dim ary1
Dim i As Long
    ary1 = Split(arg.FormulaR1C1, "+")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ary1)
        ary1(i) = Split(ary1(i), "*")(0)
    Next i
    sigmaA = Join(ary1, "+")
End Function
```